# How to calculate the number of requests per second for home LAN?

Tags: networking, lan

I am planning to build a simple DEV data center for my app out of my home LAN. I am trying to figure out (ballpark) how much load my web servers will be able to take, and need help from some network gurus in confirming my mathemtical approach.

My ISP claims my download bandwidth is 3 Mbps (0.375 MBps), and that my upload bandwidth is 1 Mbps (0.125 MBps). According to [Google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358276/4009451), the average size of an HTTP request is less than 3KB.

My first question is: **for normal HTTP requests, which do I need to care about: download or upload bandwidth?** I *believe* it would be counted towards download bandwidth, since it would all be seen as traffic coming into my router from the outside world.

Sticking with that assumption, I have 0.375 MBps of bandwidth, or 375 KBps. If the average HTTP request that I'm serving is, say, 3.75KB, then I further assume that this means, more or less, I'll be able to serve approximately 100 requests per second from my in-home web server.

My second question is: **have I done the math here right, or have I omitted a fundamental aspect of networking that would significantly impact my estimate of 100 requests/second?**

Comment: Bandwidth may not be your bottleneck. It could be some part of your server (disk/memory/number of threads/etc). You should use something like [jMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) if you really want to know the limits. "JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and dynamic resources (Files, Web dynamic languages - PHP, Java, ASP.NET, etc... It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server to test its strength/analyze overall performance under different load types."

Comment: With those speeds, I assume you're on DSL in which case your upload and download speeds affect each other. If you're using 50% of your upload speed, it reduces the available "pipe" for your download speed. Additionally, home internet connections are typically set up with larger download and smaller upload because that's what you need to browsing the internet. Datacenter connections are typically the other way around with tons of outgoing (up) speed and lower incoming (down) speed. If you're trying to host a small web service, you're probably better off looking at a VPS/cloud server for that.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill - I am familiar with jMeter. Is my approach to the calculation correct though? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @Brian - believe it or not I'm on broadband. Also definitely not looking for VPS/Cloud/PaaS/etc. Is my approach to the calculation above more or less correct? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, from a pure bandwidth side of things you do have the math correct, but as @DavidPostill mentioned, home hosting on a home PC is likely going to give other bottlenecks in the hardware as well as the delays in the network side. So the math is basically right, though there's no fault tolerance so you may want to estimate based on a higher than average request size to make sure you're a little future proof. In short though, yes you have the conversion from megabits to megabytes to kilobytes correct and you've divided the bandwidth appropriately to get a rough baseline.

Comment: Calculation looks about right. But upload/download loads do influence each other (even on cable/broadband). Think bittorrent ... if upload is saturated then download suffers as outgoing communications (acknowledgment signals, resend requests etc) will be blocked.

Comment: As a data center you may have small inbound requests (your downstream) for large data returns (your upstream) so I would expect upstream would be the internet limitation.

Comment: It isn't clear from this description what is where in the scenario.  An http *response* is almost always bigger than a *request*.  In the above, where is the web server (inside the ADSL service or outside it) and where is the client talking to the web server?  And is the client downloading from the webserver or uploading to it?

Comment: Thanks @Paul - but before I answer your question, I need to understand: what is an "ADSL service"?

Comment: @smeeb Sorry, there was an assumption earlier that the internet connection is ADSL and I followed it.  I just mean the internet connection.